# How can one solve the problem of telekinesis in interactionist dualism?

Tags: mind-body

Interactionist dualism states that the mental can effect the brain and vice versa. However, there is the problem of possible telekinesis. If the mind can effect the physical, shouldn't we be able to move things with our mind? What are some ways out of this problem?

Comment: Affecting the world with mind does not imply telekinesis. There is such a thing as limitation. And we can assume there are limitations on mental abilities regarding how much can we affect the world. However, I don't see how this is more a problem than that for a physicalist.

Comment: There is no problem, just because something can happen does not mean that it has to happen, especially in a particular way. Mental causation in any case has to comply with energy conservation, so whatever is caused by the mental has to be energy neutral, which pretty much rules out telekinesis.

Answer (score 1):

Having a testable prediction from a mind-body theory is not a "problem".  This is instead an advantage, and shows that methodological empiricism can be applied to mind-body.

The tenor of the question seens to assume that telekinesis has been shown to be false.  The opposite is the case.  Here are three of the examples of the telekinesis evidence.

http://deanradin.com/evidence/Radin1991DiceMA.pdf
https://www.neuroquantology.com/index.php/journal/article/view/670
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286873222_A_faulty_PK_meta-analysis

Telekinesis, as seen in these parapsychology experiments, is a weak phenomenon.  Interactive dualism which is consistent with these results would have to assume a weak interaction effect between mind and matter.